# How can I make defect types set automatically in Report Portal?

Tags: reportportal

I heard that [Report Portal](https://github.com/reportportal/reportportal) is able to analyse results and set defect types automatically.

I created some custom defect types in project settings in Report Portal - "Timed out", "Setup issue", etc. So now I can manually change test items' defect type to these new types.

Then I executed some launches but Report Portal didn't guess defect types properly. How does Report Portal guess defect types? What can I do to make them guessed properly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

this is right statement. Report Portal can analyze new failures, based on history of execution.

First of all, make sure you have enabled it. It's available by:

- triggering after finish
- manual triggering

As launch finalized, Report Portal will collect all failed items as `candidate` for analysis. Then collect all [investigated items][2] in a row of **4** previous launches (equal name). 
Then "Auto-Analysis" going to process all remembered failed items from current launch:

- "Auto-Analysis" took first item from remembered list and start to looking in history list investigated item with the same count of `ERROR logs`. If this item found then *error log strings* start comparing one with others via calculating `Levenshtein distance`. All digit chars are excluded from comparison to avoid date, numbers and code line number differences in stack-traces.
- If total ratio more or equals `95%` (it will be configurable in future per project) then "Auto-Analysis" setup all attributes of defect from investigated item in history to current failed item, and switching on next one failed item.

Details available here: http://reportportal.io/#documentation/Analyze-launches%3E-auto-analysis-algorithm

Picture with scheme: [ReportPortal.io auto-analysis algorithm](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NHv2.png)